# Display a non percent value for a progress bar

Tags: php, voting-system

I have this code displaying a progress bar, I will input the value as 10, 15, 20 etc.. but I would like the first `$design_value` to be displayed as a vote from 0 to 10, so I should divide the value by 10, is there an easy way to print that in php? thanks

```
<div class="small-12 medium-3 columns hide-for-small">'.$design_value.'</div>
</div>
<div class="progress"> 
    <span data-width="'.$design_value.'" style="width:'.$design_value.'%;"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php

Comment: I do not think this is about rounding a value, isn't it? For example I have 54 and I want it to be 5,4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I understood your question correctly...

```
<div class="small-12 medium-3 columns hide-for-small">'.round($design_value / 10).'</div>
</div>
<div class="progress"> 
    <span data-width="'.$design_value.'" style="width:'.$design_value.'%;"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: let's say I have 3 values like design, confort and pricing. In order to create an average value is this correct? `<div class="average">'.round(($design_value + $confort_value + $pricing_value  / 3 ) / 10).'</div>`

Comment: You need to close the () before dividing by 3, otherwise the annoying math order of operations gets in the way.

Comment: like this? `<div class="average">'.round((($design_value + $confort_value + $pricing_value) / 3 ) / 10).'</div>` thanks

Comment: You need 3 steps here. 1) Find the average of the values. 2) Divide that result by 10. 3) Round that result.